# How to start a javascript 'for of' loop at 0 (zero)?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm reading a cookie called myCookie its value is like this 1,2,3,4,9,11,23. Then I create a var testem = myCookie.split(","); Now I want to use each of the values in a 'for of' loop like this;

```
    var testem = myCookie.split(",");

    for (var i of testem) { 
      alert(testem[i]);
      toggleCol(testem[I]); 
    }
```

The problem is the alert always starts at 2 and of course the toggleCal function does also. How do I get it to start at the first value which in this case (but not always is 1)? The cookie value might be 3,4,5,6,9,12 in this case it should start at 3, but instead its starting at 4.
Can someone please explain to me why. And then tell me how to start it at the first value of myCookie not the second?

Comment: Your loop iterate over values. So "i" is a value. Not an index.

Comment: *split* returns an array, so why are you using *for..of* instead of *forEach*? And your code doesn't do what you say it's doing. Given "3,4,5,6,9,12" it will start at 3, not 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for..of` with arrays iterates over *values*, not property indicies. Use the plain value instead:

```
for (const item of testem) { 
  toggleCol(item); 
}
```

If you wanted to iterate over the property names, use a `for..in` loop instead (strongly not recommended):

```
for (const i in testem) { 
  toggleCol(testem[i]); 
}
```

Or, you might use an even more appropriate method, `forEach`:

```
testem.forEach(toggleCol); // assuming toggleCol uses exactly one argument
```

Comment: This is exactly why I ask questions, because I learn what I didn't know. I used testem.forEach and it worked perfectly.